# Web API - Inconsistent Results

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have .NET web API project that is showing some strange behavior that I really can't seem to find an answer for.

The issue is that the API is returning inconsistent results from one call to the next using the exact same parameters. To test this out, I created a postman collection and ran the call 25 times with 100ms between each call. For most of the calls, I get the results I expect:

```
{
    "Successful": true,
    "Data": [{
        "Version": 1.0,
        "Code": "BC12",
        "FN": "Mick",
        "LN": "Jager",
        "PH": "1111111111",
        "OCC": "Dentist",
        "ACT": "Y",
        "ISA": "Y",
        "DLID": "5874589",
        "CB": null,
        "CO": null
    }],
    "Exception": null,
    "ResponseCode": 200
}
```

However sometimes, I just get an empty response with no error:

```
{
    "Successful": true,
    "Data": [],
    "Exception": null,
    "ResponseCode": 200
}
```

In the past hour, I've ran the call a total of 55 times and 8 of them came back with the empty response (all in the production environment).

I did the same thing in the staging environment and 0 out of the 55 came back with the empty response.

Its returning the JSON version of my custom response so I know the code is not erroring before it can create the data. Another really strange thing about this is it only happens in the production environment. If I run the same 25 calls to the staging environment I never see the empty response and all 25 calls come back with the data. Again, each call has the exact same parameters. Has anyone seen something like this? It definitely has to be IIS or SQL server related as it doesn't happen on the Staging side and the only difference between the 2 environments is the IIS server and the SQL server. Also, the traffic to the server right now is very minimal so I don't think the amount of traffic to the server is an issue.

Comment: I believe there was an potential first chance exception thrown when your API return null response body. Have you tried to capture dump file to check what the exception is?

Comment: Maybe you are returning data before its getting ready, for example, returning `OK` before `await` for DB.